# No blogger follow or unfollow button works for me!

Tags: blogger

To follow a blog on blogger there are several ways:

- Use the "Join this site" button in the sidebar of a blog.
- Use the "Follow" button in the bar at the top of each blog.
- Use the "Add" button under the list of the blogs your follow on your blogger dashboard site.

Now I have the problem that I already followed 300 blogs and can't follow new blogs! I have to unfollow some, and there are again those 3 possibilities to unfollow a blog:

1. Use the "Join this site" button and then "unfollow."
2. Use the "Follow" button and then "unfollow."
3. Use the "Mangage" button under the list of the blogs you follow on your blogger dashboard site and then "settings" and then "unfollow."

What happens is that:

- The first option didn't work for me since I have blogger, which always says:

  > We're sorry...
  >   We were unable to handle your request. Please try again or return a bit later.
- The second option disappeared since I am following 300 blogs.
- The third option also says:

  > We're sorry...
  >   We were unable to handle your request. Please try again or return a bit later.

At the moment, I can't follow or unfollow any blog. I'm just stuck with the 300 blogs I'm following.

What can I do?

Comment: If you want to follow over 300 blogs, you'd be better off with an RSS feed reader.

Comment: Use the "Manage" button to do this

Comment: I had the same problem, I just viewed my reading list in google reader and then was able to unfollow, I hope this works!!